# Rocket.Chat Meteor server: call method after message was post?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, rocket.chat

For example: we have a user. This user post a message. I need to execute method before this message will be saved to database or right after it. Basicly I want to modify this message. Could some one help with it?

Comment: Did you looked through the rocket chat code and tried already to solve the issue?

Comment: If you know the collections those messages go into then you can use collection hooks: https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks. That package allows you to define hooks for before and after collection operations.